# Updating a Rails 2.3 app to Rails 3.0.3 but getting undefined method `allow_forgery_protection'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Updating to Rails 3.0.3/Ruby 1.9.2 but getting the following error:

https://gist.github.com/737514

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `self.allow_forgery_protection = false` in `application.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

I just got this as well. It looks like it stems from the fact that Behavior overrides ActionController::Base#config with its own method (really just to provide a helper that has the same functionality as Behavior.config... which I'm a little ticked at, but anyway...)

I've [forked "behavior" here](https://github.com/AndrewO/behavior) and tried to clean up a few other things as well (Rspec2, some other Rails 3 things). The main change is that Behavior.config has been replaced with Behavior.behavior_config (same with the ActionController::Base mixin).